# Add a class name to dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, adobe-edge

I'm trying to markup generated content, I think it'll work best if I could give the generated divs the same name.
Here's my code:

```
$.getJSON("data/reviews.json", function(data){
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    var ss = sym.createChildSymbol("Template", "content");
    ss.$("title").html( data[i].reviewer );
    ss.$("review").html( data[i].review );  

}
```

The code works, but just shows my objects underneath eachother, which isn't very pretty.I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work because my object seems to exist out of 5 different divs...

```
$( "div:last" ).addClass( "reviewdiv" );
```

Any ideas?

this is my html output:

```
<div id="Stage_content" class="Stage_content_id content" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 3091px; width: 100%; height: 758px; right: auto; bottom: auto; overflow: visible; border: 5px none rgba(63, 115, 128, 0.596078); background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
<div id="eid_1390419617256" style="position: relative; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); min-width: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 210px; max-width: 295px; width: 300px;">
... some more div id="eid_*****"...
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to markup the created "Template"'s

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class name in your loop. So:

```
$.getJSON("data/reviews.json", function(data){
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    var ss = sym.createChildSymbol("Template", "content");
    ss.$("title").html(data[i].reviewer);
    ss.$("review").html(data[i].review);  
    ss.$("review").addClass("reviewdiv");
}
```

Comment: this only gives a class to "review", I want to give a class to the parent of review, and I don't really now how to get it's name

Comment: you can use ss.$("review").parentElement